# Must cookies have an "equals" sign?

Tags: http, cookies, standards

Does using cookies without an equals sign `=` violate the HTTP standard?

For example, is this HTTP response adhering to standards? :

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: cookie_data_without_equals_sign; Domain=.foo.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT; HttpOnly
```

What about multiple equals sign, as such? :

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Content-type: text/html
Set-Cookie: key=val=ue=; Domain=.foo.com; Path=/; Expires=Wed, 13 Jan 2021 22:23:01 GMT; HttpOnly
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cookie *must* specify a **name** and a **value** separated by a `=`.  That is dictated by all cookie RFCs to date ([2109](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2109), [2965](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2965), and [6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265)) and even the original [Netscape cookie spec](http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html).

Here is the relevant ABNF from the current spec, [RFC 6265](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265):

```
 set-cookie-header = "Set-Cookie:" SP set-cookie-string
 set-cookie-string = cookie-pair *( ";" SP cookie-av )
 cookie-pair       = cookie-name "=" cookie-value
 cookie-name       = token
 cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
 cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
                        ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
                        ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
                        ; and backslash
 token             = <token, defined in [RFC2616], Section 2.2>
```

Comment: By that, do you mean that we can have multiple '='s?

Comment: Everything after the first `=` up to a `;` is the value of the cookie. The value can contain embedded `=` characters, as it falls in the `%x3C-5B` range of allowed characters.

Comment: Hmm, this is odd. The standards seem to suggest that even a single `=` would be valid... or perhaps even `==`, `======`, etc.

Comment: A cookie's *value* is arbitrary, the useragent must store and return it as-is, it only has meaning to the webserver. The first `=` separates the *name* from the *value*, everything after that up to a `;` can be whatever the webserver want it to be, as long as it conforms to relevant character restrictions imposed by the cookie RFC as well as HTTP itself for general header content. In your example, `key=val=ue=` would be a cookie named `key` with a value of `val=ue=`, which is legal.

Comment: Sry I'm abit rusty on ABNF right now, Does `token = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or separators>` mean that the cookie-name is mandatory and cannot contain `=`, Thus `=`, `==`, and `=====` are all invalid?

Comment: The `key` is mandatory by the ABNF I showed you: `cookie-pair = cookie-name "=" cookie-value`.  `=` is defined by RFC 2616 as a `separator`, so it cannot appear in a `token` and thus cannot appear in a `cookie-name`. It is allowed in a `cookie-octet` and thus is allowed in a `cookie-value`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the BNF per [rfc2965](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2965.txt):

```
   set-cookie      =       "Set-Cookie2:" cookies
   cookies         =       1#cookie
   cookie          =       NAME "=" VALUE *(";" set-cookie-av)
   NAME            =       attr
   VALUE           =       value
   set-cookie-av   =       "Comment" "=" value
                   |       "CommentURL" "=" <"> http_URL <">
                   |       "Discard"
                   |       "Domain" "=" value
                   |       "Max-Age" "=" value
                   |       "Path" "=" value
                   |       "Port" [ "=" <"> portlist <"> ]
                   |       "Secure"
                   |       "Version" "=" 1*DIGIT
   portlist        =       1#portnum
   portnum         =       1*DIGIT
```

Comment: [RFC 2965](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2965) is obsoleted by [RFC 6265](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6265). Nobody uses `Set-Cookie2`.